# How to get WBS from MPP(MS Project) file in to c# project

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I want to get WBS from ms projct and use it in my C# projct.
is there a way to do that?
How Can I use VSTO to get wbs?
acctualy I want to sync wbs to my C# project...

Any Help? thank You...